# Integral operator defined on $two$ distinct dense subspaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integral-transforms

I have decided to edit my post a bit heavily for clarity. I was trying to be fairly general but it's hard to see what I'm asking so I've decided to limit myself to a specific example which will hopefully make it clearer.

Suppose I have an integral operator $T$ that can be defined on two distinct (zero intersection) subspaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ which is not *a priori* bounded. That is to say that for $f\in S_1$ or $f\in S_2$, $Tf$ exists pointwise almost everywhere and is given by

$$Tf(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} k(x,y)f(x) dx$$

for some kernel $k$.

Suppose then that on $S_1$ I can actually show that $Tf\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\|Tf\|\le C\|f\|$. Since $S_1$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, $T$ can be extended to a bounded operator on all of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Call the extension $\widetilde{T}$.

However this extension need not (and in many cases will not) be an integral operator on all of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Clearly, $\widetilde{T}|_{S_2}$ is a bounded operator but is it the case that $\widetilde{T}|_{S_2}$ is actually an integral operator? If so, does it agree identically with the definition above?

Comment: I think cross-posting is quite strongly discouraged (as it causes wasted effort). If in doubt, a reasonable strategy is probably to post on MSE; wait a reasonable amount of time (at least a couple of days); then move to MO at that time, indicating that is what you've done on your original post. (Others may be able to give better etiquette advice here).

Comment: Alright. Guess I'll delete it then.

Comment: I'm assuming that by "identical on both subspaces" you mean that the operators agree on $H_1\cap H_2$. Then what you're suggesting will not work. For example, $H_2=H_1+ L(x)$ with $x\notin H_1$, and now you can define $Tx$ arbitrarily (since you didn't insist on $T_2$ bounded).

Comment: It's perhaps also useful to remember that two dense subspaces can have zero intersection (polynomials and $C_0^{\infty}$ in $L^2(0,1)$).

Comment: This version seems to be much more understandable.

Comment: @S.Carnahan Sorry about the previous iterations. I guess what I was asking is loosely-defined and much better understood by example.

Comment: In particular: in the new version, there are possible closed-graph type arguments which might be available, which I couldn't see in the first version for the reasons pointed out by Christian Remling and Andre Henriques. But for this to work one would still need to know more about the way the subspaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ are defined -- are they Banach spaces for some norm that dominates the $L^2$-norm they inherit as subspaces?

Comment: @YemonChoi I do not think that they are Banach spaces for any norm but I don't know how I'd go about proving that.

Comment: It is easy to show that it does not need to have the same kernel: Take $S_1$ be the space of functions that are in $L^1\cap L^2$ and have $0$ integral (it is dense in $L^2$!) and let $S_2$ be the set of all functions with compact support. Now just put $k(x,y)=1$. The extension from $S_1$ is then the zero operator. It is still integral, though, so the first of your questions requires a bit more thought.

Comment: @fedja: Your example makes an interesting point, but your subspaces intersect.

Comment: That is certainly not a problem: you can restrict the first subspace a bit more so that it won't contain any non-trivial compactly supported function (just take the linear span of some appropriate countable dense set chosen by induction so that the functions in it are linearly independent on any interval $[n,n+1]$, or something else like that).

Comment: @fedja well that is disheartening. Seems like it can't really be done unfortunately. If you want to make this an answer (counter example), I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, "its definition is identical" is not a precise mathematical notion,
it does not exclude the possibility that the operator is defined using cases.

You can take, as suggested by Christian Remling, the two dense subspaces with trivial intersection given by polynomial functions and by $C_0^\infty=\{C^\infty$ functions that vanish in a nbh of the $\partial$ $\}$ inside $L^2(0,1)$, and take the definition of your operator $A$ to be
$$
A(f)=\begin{cases}
\int_0^1 f(x)dx&\text{if $f$ is a polynomial} \\
f(\frac12) &\text{if } f\in C_0^\infty
\end{cases}
$$